# Action not found in play framework

Tags: playframework

I've just created a new play framework project and it runs fine. Now, once I modify my routes file (all I'm doing is adding the `GET /popular` line):

```
# Home page
GET     /popular                    controllers.Application.popular()
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

Now in my controller, I add the handler:

```
public class Application extends Controller {

    public static Result index() {
        return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));
    }

    public static Result popular() {

        ArrayList<String> popular = new ArrayList<String>();
        popular.add("testing");
        popular.add("123");
        return ok(Json.toJson(popular));
    }
}
```

For some reason, I'm getting a 'Action not found' when trying to access `http://127.0.0.1:9000/popular`.

I just wanted to try out a simple action. Any idea why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Ok. Apparently going into the play console and executing a 'clean' command fixes this.

Comment: Sorry, that was actually a copy/paste typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently going into the play console and executing a `clean` command fixes this. If this doesn't work, try also manually executing a `compile` command.

Comment: How are you running Play? Using "run" or "start"?

Comment: I was using 'run'. Should I've used 'start'?

Answer (score 0):

```
activator clean compile
```

from the play application folder worked for me.

then

```
activator run
```