# Play: Action Not Found

Tags: scala, http, playframework, httprequest

I am trying to access a `Play` project from a browser.

Request:

`http://localhost:9000/`

Response:

```
Action Not Found

For request 'GET /'
These routes have been tried, in this order:

1 GET     /                 controllers.WidgetController.index()
2 GET     /widgets          controllers.WidgetController.widgets()
```

Request:

`http://localhost:9000/widgets`

Response:

```
Action Not Found

For request 'GET /widgets'
These routes have been tried, in this order:

1 GET     /                 controllers.WidgetController.index()
2 GET     /widgets          controllers.WidgetController.widgets()
```

I have tried [adding and removing trailing slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26453543/784980), but it did not help.

I have tried to [`sbt clean` the project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19920060/784980), but it did not help.

**Any ideas what may be wrong here?**

Comment: Can you show the controller code?

Comment: We had the same issue when SSL configurations were not provided properly, I don't know if that's the case for you.

Comment: @AminMal I think in a framework that does routing by a routes config file, when something else is able not to let the request reach the intended controller, then the "Action Not Found" page should actually show that fact. Not let the developer start guessing what is happening. This is quite misleading.

Comment: @rapt what do you mean “something else is able not to…”? Do you already know the answer? Do you know what happens under that config file? To have some idea about the routing logic? That was just a possibility because we had actually faced it, now if it took you more than 2 seconds to figure out if you use ssl in you project or not, then idk

Comment: `controllers.WidgetController` doesn't look like a complete path. What happens, if you add your complete package path like `com.mycompany.controllers.WidgetController`? The action may not be found because those actions that you give, indeed, cannot be referenced under an incomplete path.